# RabbitMQ DefaultConsumer causing too many consumer tags

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a RabbitMQ client application that listens to a specific queue. The client creates and instance of DefaultConsumer and implements the handleDelivery method. Here is the code

```
    protected LinkedBlockingQueue<Message> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public void receiveMessages() {
        try {
//            channel.basicQos(pollCount);
            Message message = new Message();
            Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                        throws IOException {
                    long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
                    String response = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                    if (response != null) {
                        message.setId(NUID.nextGlobal());
                        message.setPayload(response);
                        message.setDeliveryTag(deliveryTag);
                        messages.add(message);
                        logger.info("Message received: ", message.getPayload());
                    }
                }
            };
            logger.debug("**********Channel status: " + channel.isOpen());
            channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while getting messages from Rabbit ", e);

        }
    }
```

The method receiveMessages() is called frequently through a thread every 500ms and drains the messages into a different List for consumption. Due to this poll on receiveMessages() I observed that the consumer tags are continuously getting created and growing when viewed through rabbit console like in the picture. Is it normal to see those increasing consumer tags?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a working solution.
As Luke Bakken highlighted there is no polling required. I just call `receiveMesssages()` only once now. Thereafter my consumer is receiving callbacks as the messages are published into the queue.

```
 protected LinkedBlockingQueue<Message> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
 public void receiveMessages() {
    try {
        Message message = new Message();
        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            long deliveryTag = delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag();
            String response = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
            if (response != null) {
                message.setId(NUID.nextGlobal());
                message.setPayload(response);
                message.setDeliveryTag(deliveryTag);
                messages.add(message);
                logger.info("Message received: ", message.getPayload());
            };
        channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while getting messages from Rabbit ", e);
    }
}
```

The rabbit console now shows only 1 consume tag entry under the bound queue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal to see those increasing consumer tags?

No, your code has an error. You need to either just use a long-running consumer or you have to cancel your consumer when you are done with it.

I can't see any need to "poll" `receiveMessages` - just let it run on its own and it will add messages to your synchronized queue as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public NotificationConsumerService(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String host, Logger logger) {
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    this.host = host;
    this.logger = logger;
}

public void consumeSliceChangeNotification() {
    connectionFactory.setHost(this.host);
    try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
         Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);

        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);
            String namespace = obj.getString("namespace");
            logger.info("The latest change notification on the " + namespace +" is available");
        };

        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true,deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { } );
    } 
    catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```